# The alternative solution to lots of ifelse statements in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement

In my wordpress site, I've made it so a particular (fontawesome) icon will show if a custom field matches a particular string. Here's the relevant code:

```
<?php $department = get_field('department'); ?>     

<?php 
if($department == "Marketing"){ echo '<i class="fa fa-paint-brush fw fa-lg"></i> ';
} elseif($department == "Client Delivery"){echo '<i class="fa fa-headphones fa-lg"></i> ';
} elseif($department == "Implementation"){echo '<i class="fa fa-gears fw fa-lg"></i> ';
} elseif($department == "Sales"){echo '<i class="fa fa-money fw fa-lg"></i> ';
} elseif($department == "Executive"){echo '<i class="fa fa-building-o fw fa-lg"></i> ';
} elseif($department == "IT"){echo '<i class="fa fa-laptop fw fa-lg"></i> ';
}
?>
```

Now this works perfectly, but I just know there is a better way to achieve this, and I believe it's using a loop and/or an associative array. I've looked into both but I'm afraid I can't get my head around it, mainly because what I want to echo, is usually dependant on only one conditional.

Comment: A switch statement; or an array that is keyed on department and holds the fa-gears/fa-paint-brush/fa-money values

Comment: I think you cannot do it.There is no common pattern them.

Comment: I think OP wants to reduce the code not alternative statement like "switch". It will not reduce his code.

Comment: It might look less ugly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$values = array(
    'Marketing' => 'fa-paint-brush',
    'Client Delivery' => 'fa-headphones',
    ...
);

echo '<i class="fa ' . $values[$department]. ' fw fa-lg"></i> ';
```

Comment: An associative array like this would be much more efficient. Not to mention tidier and easier to manage.

Comment: Thankyou! Seems tidy :)

Comment: @mark-baker am I right in thinking the [$department] is referencing the key of the $values array?

Comment: It's using the key to reference the value of that array element - see example #6 in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for your `$department`.

```
  switch ($department) {
    case 0:
        echo "$department equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "$department equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "$department equals 2";
        break;
   }
```

Comment: @AwesomeGuy I'll upvote you if you return the favor because we are both correct. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `switch` statement, I tend to use those. See for yourself:

```
    switch($department) {
          case "Marketing":
              echo "foo";
              break;
          case "Client Delivery":
              echo "bar";
              break
          default:
              echo "Not found";
    }
```

And these work very great. But there's nothing wrong with else/if

Comment: Thankyou! Preferred over @Mr-Concolato only because the numbers after case threw me off a little ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try making your class name include a fragment of the value of department like `mark` for marketing. Trim the department string and insert it into the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $department = get_field('department'); ?>     

<?php 
switch(strtolower($department)) {
    case "marketing" : {
        echo '<i class="fa fa-paint-brush fw fa-lg"></i> ';
        break;
    }
    case "client delivery" : {
        echo '<i class="fa fa-headphones fa-lg"></i> ';
        break;
    }
    // ... finish all of your cases
    default : {
        echo "<font color='red'>Unknown department received : " .  $department ."</font>";
    }
}
?>
```